# Xamarin.iOS and SOAP

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, xamarin.ios

For quite some weeks I have been trying to set up a Xamarin based iOS client which communicates with a SOAP service. Setting up an unencrypted communication was no problem, but I cound not find any solution for secured communication based on certificates.

My first attempt was to use a proxy according to the corresponding Xamarin guide. This did not work because Xamarin does not support DnsEndpointIdentity for iOS in a proper way.

The second attempt was to do it without proxy. Instead I wanted to rely on System.Net.Http and self-created XML. This time I stumbled upon missing EncryptedXml members.

To make a long story short: I have the strong impression that the amount of lacking features in Xamarin's "2.0.5.0 libraries" prevents it from being general purpose.

Therefore my question: Is there anybody who managed to set up encrypted WCF/SOAP communication for a Xamarin.iOS client? If yes, what is the key to a proper solution?

Kind regards,

Stefan